# Symfony2: How to link CSS to HTML part?

Tags: html, css, symfony, web

I'm new to Symfony2 and all this website development stuff. So I already wrote my code in /WebBundle/Resources/Views/Default/index.html.twig and some CSS code just to test it. The problem is, I don't know how to link the two. I tried looking it up online, but none of it solved my problem. In my index.html.twig file, I tried:

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/WebBundle/css/web.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endblock %}
```

and

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/web.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: where you put your css file (web.css) ?

Comment: It's in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Acme/WebBundle/Resources/public/css/web.css

Or basically... /Symfony/src/Acme/WebBundle/Resources/public/css/web.css

Comment: Did you try to clear cache and re-install assets? If you didn't; open your console and type php app/console assets:install web --symlink ---Note: --symlink option is optional. If you want to hardcopy files to your web directory don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use assetic :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        '@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/public/css/web.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

In your `config.yml` tell `symfony` that your bundle will use `assetic`:

```
assetic:
    bundles:        [AcmeWebBundle]
```

Finally when passing to production you have to dump your css and/or your js buy executing :

`php app/console assetic:dump`

Further infos : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Answer (score 1):

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        '@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/public/css/web.css'
        '@AcmeWebBundle/Resources/public/css/reset.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Assuming your files *web.css, reset.css* are located in `Acme\WebBundle\Resources\public\css`

Comment: and don't forget to dump them when going to production `php app/console assetic:dump`

Comment: reset.css? What's that? I only made web.css :\

Comment: well then don't use that line.. it was only to show that it can be used for multiple files

Comment: Okay so I tried doing what you told me and I got this...

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("You must add AcmeWebBundle to the assetic.bundle config to use the {% stylesheets %} tag in AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig.") in "AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig"." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3124

Comment: I replaced "asset_url" with "bundles/AcmeWebBundle/css/web.css".